# Transition from old Java to Play, Servlet issue

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have to move from an old Java code to a new one using Play! Framework.

In the old code, I called a Java servlet using Ext-Js (Javascript Framework) using this way :

```
function getTree()
{
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', 
{
    root: 
    {
        text: 'System',
        id: 'root',
        expanded: true
    },
    proxy: 
    {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'TreeServlet',
        extraParams:
        {
            mode:'getChildren'
        },
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            root:'result'
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I would like to use Play! to do the same, but I do not know how to use it.

. **In routes.conf:** 
    `GET    /tree                       controllers.Application.makeTree()`

. **In controller.Application:**

```
public static Result makeTree(){
        // What shoul I put here to call the "Servlet"  
    }
```

I do not want to use Servlet, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for you help!

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you to all of you!

Here is how I eventually manage to achieve my goal:

```
public class Tree extends Controller
{
    private MenuManager menuManager; 
    String node; 
    String mode; 
    String hash; 
    ObjectNode response; 

    public void createTree() throws IOException{
        this.menuManager = MenuManager.getMenuManager(); 
        getParams(); 
        createJson(mode, node, hash);
    }

    public static Result returnJson() throws IOException{
        Tree t = new Tree(); 
        t.createTree();
        return ok(t.response); 
    }
```

}

And in **routes**:

```
GET     /tree                       controllers.Tree.returnJson()
```

What do you guys think? Good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier play frameworks you have to create only static methods for each and every request handler in controller.
But in the newer version (after play 2.0) you don't need to have static methods you can use normal public methods and configure it in routes prefixed with '@' symbol.

And don't maintain or declare attributes within controller class.
Because play is an event driven framework not like oridinary servlet based framework.
It provides REST and it doesn't maintain any httpsession like in servlets.
Session is available in the form of cookies only.

Below is the remodified version of your code,

```
public class TreeController extends Controller
{

    public void createTree() throws IOException{
        MenuManager menuManager = MenuManager.getMenuManager(); 
        String mode = request().getQueryString("mode");
    String node = request().getQueryString("node");
    String hash = request().getQueryString("hash");
    TreeNodeDto treeObject = menuManager.buildTree();
    ok(treeObject.toJson());
    }

}

public class BaseDto<T extends BaseDto<T>> implements Serializable{

    public JsonNode toJson() {
        return Json.toJson(this);
    }

    public T fromJson(JsonNode jsonObject) {
        return (T) Json.fromJson(jsonObject, this.getClass());
    }
}

public static class TreeNodeDto extends BaseDto {
    public String hash;
    public String name;
    public Set<TreeNodeDto> children;

    // Override equals and hashcode, because we are using "set" to maintain the child nodes.

    }
```

routes

```
GET     /tree                       @controllers.TreeController.createTree()
```

Hope this will give some ideas.

Cheers..!!!

Comment: Waow! Mind blow. Very usefull in my Play understanding, Thanksss !

Comment: Go to playframework page and see the basic documentations and tutorials. It will some more things to you.

Comment: I've already been there, but there is not a lot of doc. Shame because Play! looks pretty awesome.

Comment: Cool. Dont worry about that. Just learn the basic things (Necessary actions ) from their site. Once you have done then start looking at the blogs. But 60% of blogs written for play with scala. but you can understand those too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the WS object: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWS

It seems that the return from the Servlet is a Json so check how to process json in play here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJsonActions

I believe something like that should do it

```
public static Promise<Result> makeTree() {
    final Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url("TreeServlet").setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").get().map(
            new Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WSResponse response) {
                    return ok("Feed title:" + response.asJson().findPath("result"));
                }
            }
    );
    return resultPromise;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Thing is, by doing like that, I still have tou use the Servlet, right ? (so, the service method). Is there any way to avoid that ? (And even by using the servlet, I got a 500 Http error.)

Comment: If you can re-write the old code in the play framework then you can remove the servlet but if this is not possible then, your old code needs to run in an application server and you have to call this code from play. Try to add a network proxy like wireshark or tcpmon to capture the calls between the ext and servlet and play and servlet to see what is happening there. Also maybe you need the absolute url in the WS.url call e.g. http://localhost:8080/TreeServlet

Answer (score 0):

Below is the structure for your http request in play,

```
 public static Result makeTree() {
            TreeDto treeDto=new TreeDto();
            JsonNode jsonResponse = Json.newObject();
            try {
                treeDto = <<Logic to get the tree objects from db>>;
                if(treeDto != null) {           
                    jsonResponse = Json.toJson(treeDto);
                }
            } catch (XODAOException e) {
                Logger.error("Error while building the tree.", e);
                jsonResponse = generateErrorResponse("Error while building tree.", e);
            } 
            return ok(jsonResponse);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my initial question, what do you think?